# Object is identified when script runs in maintenance mode and not when script is executed in normal run mode

Tags: ui-automation, hp-uft

Home page of the AUT shows the name of the logged in user. 
On spying the object using UFT, it shows the below properties:

```
"Class Name:=WebElement",
"abs_x:=718",
"abs_y:=127",
"class:=<class>",
"height:=27",
"html id:=",
"html tag:=DIV",
"innerhtml:=firstname lastname",
"innertext:=firstname lastname",
"outerhtml:=<div class=""<value>"" ng-bind=""lc\.userName"">firstname lastname</div>",
"outertext:=firstname lastname",
"role:=",
"title:=",
"type:=",
"visible:=True",
"width:=164",
"x:=718",
"xpath:=//DIV\[@id=""<value>""\]/DIV\[1\]/DIV\[2\]",
"y:=76"
```

Script uses the class property to identify the object

```
Set WBLogin=Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebElement("class:=value")
```

When script is executed in maintenance run mode, UFT is able to recognize the object using above statement.
However, when script is executed in normal run mode, UFT fails to identify the object as value in variable `WBLogin` is empty

Comment: Can you post relevant HTML source code...?

Comment: What is the actual value of the class ?

Please check if it has any regular expression operators like '.' or '*'. That can cause the interference while execution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try reading all child objects of class *webelement* & try to identify if you could locate an object with class property "value".